# How to setup same ImageView size on different screens?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview, dimensions

I was hoping that DP pixels are solving issue of different screen sizes.

I've set up my ImageView as this:

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:src="@drawable/center_ring"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>
```

Then I tried to launch this app on virtual devices of Nexus 5X and Nexus S with different screen sizes. As you can see relative size of ImageView is quite different.

How do I get same relative size on different screens?

[image]
[image]

Comment: use dimen file for multiple size support or create different size of images and put them in the drawable folders (hdpi , xhdpi , xxhdpi etc) accordingly

Comment: @AdeelTurk that might solve graphics issue, but my other items are custom TextView objects and I still need a way to make them of same relative size in all screens.

Answer (score 1):

try using this library for your dimension. this will help you overcome your issues but its not a ideal solution , ideally i would recommend you to use constraint layout or layout weights 
https://github.com/intuit/sdp

This shall help you get screen size

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);
int width = size.x;
int height = size.y;
```

Comment: I dont think ConstraintLayout would work, as this app is an educational game where objects (custom TextViews, ImageViews) are dragged around, overlap and react on collision.

Comment: I've tried your suggested Android SDK with SDP units. They are more consistent, but still not pixel perfect. Besides, many of my objects are created programmatically - can I use these units within JAVA code?

Comment: yes you can , but define those sizes in dimen xml and then call them in ur code

Comment: I'll try this approach. Quite shocked Android doesnt have native tools for this. I guess in the future my game should be rewritten without using any views and drawing all elements myself.

Comment: android has a support , that is giving sizes in dp , but i guess due to huge range of screen size and resolutions available ,it doesnt give optimal performance everywhere,however i hope you find a apt solution , if u do , do post it as an answer and also consider voting this answer if it helped u

Comment: I wonder if I could solve this by using xdpi and ydpi values of DisplayMetrics to calculate same relative sizes. Have no idea how accurate these are across different devices.

Comment: one approach you can take is to get the device size first hand , then try to calculate your sizes accordingly,lengthy sure but should work for u

Comment: Is there a way to find device size? I tried setting dimensions calculated by xdpi and ydpi values of DisplayMetrics, but relative sizes are inconsistent at all (at least on virtual devices).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by giving width and height as px instead dp.
For same relative size you can use layout weight for used and un-used area. It'll solve your problem.

**Edit**
Then you should have custom views and create all views as per weight calculations. Then only you'll achieve this.

Comment: Using px instead of dp doesn't solve the problem. I cant use layout weight, because all my items (imageviews, custom textviews) are draggable items